# Stata import delimited when newline in data field

Tags: import, newline, stata, delimited

I want to import data from a CSV file into Stata. The problem is that sometimes, there is a newline inside a string.

Example input CSV:

```
Smith, "John F."
Kennedy, "Michael
J."
```

How can I import this into Stata?

Comment: Look at the reference below for a discussion of a similar problem. [http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1186430-end-of-file-problems](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1186430-end-of-file-problems)

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with the filefilter command. The problem is that I cannot replace the newline with anything because that of course messes up the entire CSV file, which needs to have a newline at the end of every record

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29378372/2077064 for a similar question, with answers.

Comment: Thanks Roberto, I did not find this entry when I had searched stackoverflow before! Adding bindquote(strict) to my import delimited solved it for me!